# Always getting result of 0 when counting patterns in string

Tags: javascript

I keep getting a result of 0 whenever I type in a search term. I'm trying to find the number of times that a pattern occurs in string. So for example searching for **at** would return **3**. Any advice on where I'm going wrng?

```
string =
[
"cat math path"
]

    var pattern = prompt('Please enter a search term:'); 

        function check(string,pattern)
        {

            if(pattern) 
            {
                if(pattern.indexOf(string) == -1) 
                {
                return 0;
                }

                return count(pattern.substring(pattern.indexOf(string)+string.length), string)+1;
            }

            else 
            {
                return("Nothing entered!");
            }
        }

        alert(check(string,pattern));
```

Comment: 2 problems I see right away: You're defining `string` as an array with `[]`. Then you have `indexOf` backwards.  You should be doing `string.indexOf(pattern)` since it's the pattern you want to search for in string.

Comment: Also, JavaScript has no native `count()`. Are you using some other library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(pattern.indexOf(string) == -1)
```

should be

```
if(string.indexOf(pattern) == -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you inverted the use of `pattern` and `string`. See the documentation of `indexOf`. Also you can easily count occurrences with `split` which breaks your string into an array:

`count=string.split(pattern).length - 1;`

Where `string="cat math path";` (instead of an array)